How to identify video segments of camera pov: rotating around itself or orbiting around object via opencv
I'm trying to build an automated system that will recognise the following types of segments of a video:

camera POV is orbiting around an object (this will be mostly in the centre of the frame at all times)
camera POV is rotating around itself, horizontally
camera POV is rotating around itself vertically

What would be the easiest way to build this with openCV? Obviously there are intermediate sections of the video that are not relevant - that is, transitioning from one type of movement to the next.
I'm thinking the following approach:

define the pattern for both of these types of movement (how?). These can be anything from 30 seconds or several minutes. It needs to accurate recognise which is the starting frame and what is the ending frame for the type of movement (which algorithm is best for this?).
for each type, loop over the frames of the video and record the starting and ending timestamps of the relevant sections (there might be multiple)


that is Structure from Motion. -- you are holding back. there is more going on. your motion is highly unlikely to consist purely of rotations. in fact, the change of rotation centers constitutes translation. what is the application? be the extreme opposite of abstract/general. give a concrete example (data), not a toy/simplified example.

thx, would optical flow work for this?

that's impossible to answer without some data. I asked for data and details.

If you need to build a 3d world view then you will need to use structure from motion, a library like opensfm.
If you're primarily concerned with detecting motion in a video like a drone video or aerial photography, then you're probably looking for optical flow.
Pseudo code
import cv2
while cap.isOpened():
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if not ret:
            break

        frame_gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        p1, st, err = cv2.calcOpticalFlowPyrLK(old_gray, frame_gray, p0, None, **lk_params)
        good_new = p1[st == 1]
        good_old = p0[st == 1]

        motion = classify_motion(good_new, good_old)


def classify_motion(good_new, good_old):
    # Classify the motion based on patterns in motion vectors
    motion_vectors = []

    for i, (new, old) in enumerate(zip(good_new, good_old)):
        a, b = new.ravel()
        c, d = old.ravel()
        motion_vectors.append(((a - c), (b - d)))

    avg_vector = np.mean(motion_vectors, axis=0)
    movement_magnitude = np.linalg.norm(avg_vector)

    # Heuristics for determining motion type
    if movement_magnitude < 1:  # Small movement, likely Pan
        return "Pan"
    elif np.std([v[0] for v in motion_vectors]) < 2 and np.std([v[1] for v in motion_vectors]) > 5:
        return "Dolly"  # Mostly lateral movement
    elif np.std([v[0] for v in motion_vectors]) > 5 and np.std([v[1] for v in motion_vectors]) < 2:
        return "Flyover"  # Mostly vertical movement


